# Elegant and functional solution to linear optimization constraint?

Tags: excel, optimization, constraints

Assume you have a linear optimization problem where you are trying to determine which attendees of a corporate event qualify to go through to the VIP event. You are trying to maximize a pre-defined utility, where each attendee has a particular utility, subject to a number of constraints which include:

- No more than 4 people from any company at the VIP event
- At least 4 companies represented at the VIP event.

Assume you have 400 attendees and only 10 can attend the VIP event, and there are employees from at least 50 different companies to choose from.
I have set up my problem in excel, where I have a row for each attendee, and a binary column for my linear optimization program’s ‘changeable cells’, where 1 is selected if the attendee is chosen for the VIP event and 0 otherwise.

What code can I then write to satisfy the above constraints?

What I have tried so far…

Currently my only solution for dealing with the first constraint listed above is to have 50 additional binary columns (one for each company) where if an attendee is going to the VIP event and they are from the company represented in that particular column, it will list a ‘1’, and ‘0’ otherwise. Then have another 50 cells that sum each column and then set a constraint that says those cells must be less than or equal to 4.

I feel there must be a more elegant and efficient way of doing this however.

I also cannot currently think of a way to write the code to satisfy the second constraint. I have tried having a separate column that displays company names when the changeable cell equals 1, then counting the number of unique values in that column, and then applying a constraint to that cell such that it must be greater than or equal to 3, but apparently that is a “non-linear” constraint.

Comment: could you post your formluas? or upload a screenshot to imgur?

Comment: You don't need the second constraint. If there are 10 attendees and the first constraint is satisfied then automatically the second constraint is also satisfied. It is unclear what your data layout is and how you currently handle 400+ variables.

Comment: @user3964075, my mistake. I have changed it to 4.

Comment: Having no idea how your data is set up or if you have any other requirements you haven't shared, with such a small data set (400 rows) why not just sort it by company name and take the first name for each of the first 10 companies.  Boom, all requests satisfied (10 people, 1 from each company, and 10 companies represented).

Comment: @Tom here is a screenshot of the draft of my linear optimisation. http://i.imgur.com/p51IkMl.png Hopefully you can see I have binary columns for just 4 companies right now, that just copies the Changeable Cell column "E", if the individual is from the company listed in column header. I currently just then sum these columns and set a constraint that the sum must be less than 4. I have to do one of these for every company (50+), however, and sometimes companies change. I would like to find an elegant way of saying "no more than 4 from ANY company" + "4 different companies represented".

Comment: @sous2817, thanks for your thoughts, this would satisfy the constraints but wouldn't maximise the utility variable (seen in column D of the screenshot above). I trying to maximize the utility whilst meeting the constraints.

Comment: @WillT-E your current model already exceeds solver limitations - max 200 variable cells, while you have 400 binary variable (1 for each attendee) +more. If you can sort your attendee list by Utility descending, you can apply simple algorithm to choose best combination: start choosing top rows and make sure to discard 5th (or next) attendees from a single company. Change algorithm for the 10th candidate - make sure there are 4 different companies chosen, you can implement it all using simple formulas.

Comment: @user3964075 thanks for your feedback, I use a program called OpenSolver that can handle more than 200 variable cells. Regarding the algorithm, do you mean write something in VBA to perform the tasks you outlined?

Comment: @WillT-E you should be able to achieve it without VBA (only simple formulas like `IF`, `COUNTIF`, `SUM` to determine top 10 attendees metting all criteria, but you need to sort the list first. If you upload sample file I can help you with the formulas.

Comment: @user3964075 here is a draft of the problem. I have reduced it to less than 200 variables and just 4 companies, and only included the info for the relevant constraints, The real problem is much larger. I have also disabled the macros that are present in the main file too. Hopefully this is all the info you need to demonstrate how you would solve the problem, but let me know if not: https://www.dropbox.com/s/49bua6cs8td4c6a/VIPdraft.xlsx?dl=0